# How do I get my icons binded in my Android Application?

Tags: java, android, icons, android-arrayadapter

I have following (relevant) classes:

```
public class Category {

    private int icon;
    private String name;

getters; setters;
}
```

and

```
public class Location {
    ...
    ...
    private Set<Category> categories;
    ...
}
```

and an ArrayAdapter which plots my Location into an arraylist and displays them in a ListView, I have like 100 icons, I want to display them beside my List-Items, which are coded in JSON-Type, and it has an int icon. Now I wish to get an icon for each number in my arraylist, how do I do that?
My Adapter has the following: final ImageView ic = (ImageView) viewInRow.findViewById(R.id.icon);

This is a part of my xml-file:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:src="@drawable/icon0001" />
```

I am not sure about android:src, because it just points to a single file, while I have plenty.
Did I do something wrong with my XML? I can't get the icons to be displayed. Since the icons are attributes of "Category", which is a Set, I have to use an iterator to go over the elements and then do: .getIcon(); which yields the int, which I need for my mapping: setImageResource( ... );

Now how do I exactly do this? Something seems to go wrong and I get no Icons displayed... Can anyone please help me?
If something is unclear, please ask.

Comment: There should be a place where you create a View for each row. In the method, an index will be passed in as a parameter for you to use to reference index of the Category. As such, you will need to add your set to a List so you can reference by Index. Once you figure out which Category it is, you can set Icon.

Comment: So I have to cast the Set to a List? I got the view for each row, I can get Positions too but as said before i got a Set of category and can only iterate over These... Can you provide a sample Code?

Comment: ImageView ic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

     ic.setImageResource(itemsArrayList.get(position).getCategories().iterator().next().getIcon());

But I get no icons displayed...

Comment: I see what your dilemma is. You have a List of Locations, but each location has a dynamic amount of Categories. Everytime a row is created you will only have one Image View to populate. What you are looking for is to create N amount of ImageView so you will need to embed a new View into the row View.

Comment: Okay, how can I achieve that?